# no row at position 0 OleDb database

Tags: c#, database

Im trying to add a change password feature to my program but it keeps pulling up errors. this is the code thats supposed to run when you click on save:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = (@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\User\Desktop\esoft\gym\gym\bin\Debug\Clients.accdb");

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE username='"+textBox1.Text+ "' AND password='" + textBox2.Text + "'",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con.Open();
        errorProvider1.Clear();
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            if (textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text)
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE login WHERE username ='" + textBox1.Text + "', password='" + textBox2.Text + "' (password ='" + textBox3.Text + "')", con);
                sda.Fill(dt);
                MessageBox.Show("password successfully changed", "success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3, "passwords dont match");
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox4, "passwords dont match");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "wrong username");
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2, "wrong pasword");

        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

the main error for now is that when trying to save, it pulls up an error stating that no rows were found at position 3. when changed to [1][5] it pulls up the same error for that position.

i changed the code using your suggestions, yet still get the same error.

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\User\Desktop\esoft\gym\gym\bin\Debug\Clients.accdb"))
        {


            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(" ExecuteScalar FROM login WHERE username='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            con.Open();
            errorProvider1.Clear();
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                if (textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text)
                {
                    //   OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE login SET password ='" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE username ='" +textBox2.Text+"'");

                    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE login SET password = '" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE username = '" +textBox2.Text+"'",con);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //    sda.Fill(dt);
                    MessageBox.Show("password successfully changed", "success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3, "passwords dont match");
                    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox4, "passwords dont match");
                }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this line `OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login WHERE username='"+textBox1.Text+ "' AND password='" + textBox2.Text + "'",con);` you declare it but never execute the code to fill the `OleDbDataAdapter` and you should use `ExecuteScalar` if you are returning only a single row google the difference when you have time

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a few things wrong;

- Use `ExecuteScalar` for your `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement which is exactly what this for.
- *Even* if you don't, you don't fill your `dt` after all.
- You need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` for your  `UPDATE` statement. `DataAdapter` is for returning some data.
- You forget to use `SET` in your `UPDATE` statement.
- You need to use `AND` or `OR` for multiple `WHERE` conditions, not `,`.
- You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- Use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.
- Do not store your passwords as a plain text. Read: [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/447156)
- password is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266) in OLE DB Provider. Based on your database manager case sensitive settings, you might need to use is as `[password]`. But as a better way, change it to *non*-reserved word even if it is.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are missing a `SET` keyword. Your query

```
UPDATE login WHERE username ='" +
```

Should be

```
UPDATE login SET columnname = value WHERE username ='" +
```

Per your posted code looks like it should be

```
UPDATE login SET password ='" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE username ='" +
```

None the less, use a parameterized query and don't concatenate user input like the way you are doing right now else you have opened the door for SQL Injection.